# Creating lightning in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, effects

Does anyone know how the lightning in this video was made?

https://youtu.be/nz7tM_KLCSM?t=51m24s

I need lightning for my scene but I don't know how to make it for Cycles. I only found an old tutorial from Blender Guru for the Blender Render Engine. I would be really happy if anyone could help me.